# Как правильно начать использовать TCP socket react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, сокет, react-native, tcp

Не получается заставить работать пакет react-native-tcp-socket. Он корректно устанавливается, в нужном мне компоненте я его импортирую и пытаюсь произвести подключение

```
import React from 'react';
import {StyleSheet, Text, View, StatusBar, Platform, Dimensions, Linking, AsyncStorage, Button} from 
'react-native';
import TcpSocket from 'react-native-tcp-socket';

export class FirstAuth extends React.Component {
sendDataToServer() {
    const client = TcpSocket.createConnection({port: 11111 host: "myhost"}, () => {});
    client.write('Hello server!');
    client.destroy();
}

render() {
    return (
        <View style={{backgroundColor: "#3979c1", flex: 1}}>
            <Button
                title="SEND"
                onPress={() => this.sendDataToServer()}
            />
        </View>
    );
}
}
```

В package.json

```
"react-native-tcp-socket": "^4.5.1",
```

Вылетает с ошибкой

```
TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'p.connect')
```

В мануале написано что автолинкинг делать не нужно на этой версии реакта.

Comment: но ведь в [example](https://github.com/Rapsssito/react-native-tcp-socket#client) написано иначе?..

Comment: Я так тоже пробовал, для наглядности здесь просто упростил код.

Answer (score 1):

Проблема была в том, что я использовал EXPO, а в нем TCP socket не работает. Необходимо извлечь проект из экспо и использовать react native cli, может быть кому-то будет полезным.